Disable animation settings not being saved
I'm trying to disable animations on my ubuntu 24.04, but after every reboot the settings reset. I've tried with gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false and by changing manually through settings, but the problem still persists. I dont know if i broke some kind of config file.
